# Convert 1D numpy array to 1D numpy column column, python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and numpy, I would like to know how to convert 1D array and 2D array into one column:
for example:

```
import numpy as np 
x=np.array([1,2,3,4]) #so I need it to be as:
#x=[1
 #  2
  # 3
   #4]

 y=np.array([[1,2,3]
             [4,5,6]]
 #y=[ 1
 #    4
  #   2
   #  5
    # 3
     #6]
```

Comment: Have you tried googling "NumPy flatten array", followed by "NumPy reshape array"? Stack Overflow is _not_ a human-powered search engine

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html `np.reshape((-1, 1))` will make an array that has one in the second dimension

Comment: np.ravel(y) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html

Comment: A 1D array is an 1D array. There are no "rows" or "columns". If you want a column-like array, it has to be at least 2D, with shape (x, 1).

Comment: @ForceBru 

Thank you for your comment, however flatten return matrix only and convert it to an 1D array (row) I wanna it as a column

Comment: @Reti43
Thank you so much , but can not I convert 1D array to be as column vector ?
same as in Matlab (:) ? or transpose ?

Thank you again

Comment: Please for anyone, please add an answer, so i could accept 
It's only what i wanna is convert row or 1D array and 2D to be as vector ?

Comment: Numpy isn't Matlab. A 1D array does not have row or column orientation. But if you want to do matrix multiplication with a row and column vector, it works just fine with a 1D array. `x.dot(x)` for example.

Comment: @Sci_tech, that's why the second search I suggested was "NumPy reshape array". You want to reshape your array to have shape `(n_rows, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB all matrices are 2d (or higher), A column vector has size `(n,1)`.  It also has a `(:)` and `(:)'` idiom for 'flattening'.

In `numpy` arrays can be 1d, with shape `(n,)` (that's a 1 element tuple). But with `reshape` you can easily make it (n,1) or (1,n).  `reshape(-1,1)` is can be used (does MATLAB allow something like ([],1)` for that?)

Here's an example of playing with your `y`:

```
In [112]: y=np.array([[1,2,3],
     ...:              [4,5,6]])
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [113]: y
Out[113]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [114]: y.ravel()
Out[114]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [115]: y.ravel(order='F')          # matlab is fortran order
Out[115]: array([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6])
In [116]: y.ravel(order='F')[:,None]
Out[116]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [2],
       [5],
       [3],
       [6]])
```

Note that the nested `[]` are an essential part of the display.  [116] is a (6,1) array.

```
In [117]: x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [118]: x[:,None]
Out[118]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
In [119]: x.reshape(-1,1)
Out[119]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```